# NIDS on bridged firewall

Tags: linux, debian, firewall, bridge, intrusion-detection

I have a firewall (Debian Stable 7.5) which works in bridged mode. The interfaces `eth0` (WAN) and `eth1` (LAN) are linked with the bridge interface `br0`.

Can I deploy a NIDS (eg. [Snort](https://snort.org)) on this server? If so, which interface should it listen on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in this case it should sniff traffic on `br0`.  However, if its rules don't care about source addresses and you don't want to block or alert to potential outbound intrusions (and why not?) you can most likely sniff on the WAN interface without harm.

Sniffing is passive, more or less, and just allows you to inspect everything going over an interface.